# Macro/VBA to merge rows for non-unique

Tags: excel, merge, duplicates, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a data connection to a tab delineated text file.  The text file is generated by using the export feature from a program called NetScan by SoftPerfect.  Each report is real-time and does not include data from computers that are not currently turned on or connected to the network.  This means that a newer report might be missing a computer that an older report had but it might also contain updated information for a computer that had more memory added or something else like that.

So, on the spreadsheet I can refresh the data connection to update from the text file but since the text file is being appended to rather than replaced each time I wind up with a LOT of duplicate computer entries (the entire row may or may not be completely duplicate).  I'd like to merge the rows so that I have one row for each computer.

Small piece of sample data (all fake) - note that there are many more columns in the full spreadsheet but this sample data contains all the info that I plan to filter/merge by:

```
A               B           C                   D               E       F
IP Address      Host Name   MAC Address         Response Time   Dups    Serial Number
192.168.1.110   CLT-001     XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:C5   0 ms            2       ABC123
192.168.1.174   CLT-001     XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:FE   5 ms            1       ABC123
192.168.1.110   CLT-001     XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:C5   1 ms            2       ABC123
192.168.1.138   CLT-004     XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:04   1 ms            2       DEF456
192.168.1.146   CLT-009     XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:8E   1 ms            2       GHI789
192.168.1.121   CLT-004     XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:04   1 ms            2       DEF456
192.168.1.146   NA          XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:8E   1 ms            2       NA
192.168.1.152   CLT-005     XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:6B   1 ms            1       JKL012
```

The Serial Number is how to identify a unique computer but sometimes the scan cannot obtain the S/N (WMI error) in which case the next best bet is MAC Address.  The problem with MAC Address is that most of these laptops will eventually wind up registering 2 per computer - one for wired and one for wireless.

I tried using `=COUNTIF(Row,ItemToCount)` (that's what column E is in the example data) but I'm not sure how to use the information I get from it.  Also, this whole thing needs to be done in VBA so I can include it in my data cleanup button on the main sheet of the workbook.  My goal is to end up with data that looks like this:

```
A               B           C                   D               E       F
IP Address      Host Name   MAC Address         Response Time   Dups    Serial Number
192.168.1.110   CLT-001     XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:C5   0 ms            1       ABC123
192.168.1.146   CLT-009     XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:8E   1 ms            1       GHI789
192.168.1.121   CLT-004     XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:04   1 ms            1       DEF456
192.168.1.152   CLT-005     XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:6B   1 ms            1       JKL012
```

One concept I considered was using the Response Time to indicate whether the connection was wired or wireless which should be accurate enough for my purposes.  0 or 1ms indicates wired while 2ms or more indicates wireless.  The other option is to add more WMI calls to identify the type of network card that way and filter them out before the report even gets to the exported text file.

At this point, any help would be appreciated.  The closest thing I could find on these forums was the [Conditional Removal of Duplicates from Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/635489/conditional-removal-of-duplicates-from-excel) question.  Other forums such as mrexcel, excelforum, and ozgrid didn't have any obvious answers either although there are so many posts with nearly similar questions that finding what I'm looking for is rather difficult.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:
I find formulas work so much easier/faster than vba .. so I try to use vba as little as possible.

First, create a new column, with the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(F2,OFFSET(F2,-1*(ROW(G2)-1),0,ROW(G2)-1,1),0)), FALSE, TRUE)
```

The intent of that formula is to return TRUE if the current record is a duplicate of anything above it. For now, it just checks the Serial Number, however, in the FALSE section, you could dup the logic a little and change the columns to check the MAC Address in a similar fashion if you wanted.

I added that formula in column G.  In cell H1, I added this formula:

```
=COUNTA(G:G)
```

(I also named this cell "numrows" )

Then in vba, I did the following:

```
  Sub Macro1()
    Dim r As Integer

    r = Range("numrows").Value

    For i = r To 2 Step -1
      If Cells(i, 7).Value Then
          Rows(i).Select
          Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
          Cells(i, 1).Select
      End If
    Next i
  End Sub
```

and that seems to do the trick.
by keeping the formula outside of vba, it should make it a bit easier to tweak it to help id the records. Then the vba script simply looks for that "trigger" column, and deletes based on this.
This actually allows you to "override" manually if you wanted, to delete a record or two that you know you want gone.

Comment: I wanted to post on here that this is good information although I was unable to use it to solve my problem.  Hopefully it'll help someone else though.

Comment: Oh? why not? did it throw an error? or just additional requirements you have that screw it up? ;)

Comment: Additional requirements.  Lack of a single unique column that I could rely on to always be present added to the complexity.  Basically, the data coming in wasn't enough to perform the automation I desired.  I'm not familiar with this site's etiquette, should I upvote your solution since the information is valid for the small sample I posted?

Comment: Hmm .. not really sure myself :) lol   I suppose you could do that, and post another question with more info, or just update your original post with the additional info ... either's fine I suspect. :)